# Passing Python List in SQL Query and stored as list

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a scenario in which i have to store python list in database via python script. i have seen lot of solution like converting it into tuple or removing quotes around a string. but it want to store it into database in python list format.

```
['abc@gmaill.com', 'abc2@gmail.com', 'abc3@gmail.com', 'abc4@gmail.com', 'abc5@gmail.com', 'abc6@gmail.com', 'abc7@gmail.com', 'abc8@gmail.com', 'abc9@gmail.com']
```

and my query is

```
sql_test = "UPDATE log_messages SET unique_arguments =  %s , sent_to =  %s where log_id = %s " %  (unique_arguments_list,email_send_to,str(log_id))
```

and getting this error

```
syntax error at or near "["
LINE 1: UPDATE log_messages SET unique_arguments =  ['abc@gmaill.com...
                                                ^
```

Comment: Obviously string representation of list results in non-valid sql syntax, you have to either fix it (wrapping list in `"` quotation marks may be sufficient) of find other efficient way of serializing your list.

Comment: Obviously, I know this, that is why i ask here for any alternative

Comment: It's not clear what database / python interface you are using.

Comment: @MikeT python script with postgresql database

Comment: It's still not clear what python interface you are using, e.g. psycopg2, pygresql, pyodbc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. You are not enclosing your list string within quotes.

```
sql_test = "UPDATE log_messages SET unique_arguments =  \"%s\" , sent_to =  %s where log_id = %s " %  (unique_arguments_list,email_send_to,str(log_id))
```

Comment: this way, String breaks from \"

Comment: What do you mean by "String breaks"?

Comment: as you suggest, the query becomes `UPDATE log_messages SET unique_arguments = "['5_7_Newsletter_abc@gmail.com', '5_7_Newsletter_abc2@gmail.com', '5_7_Newsletter_abc3@gmail.com', '5_7_Newsletter_abc4@gmail.com', '5_7_Newsletter_abc5@gmailvalid.com', '5_7_Newsletter_abc6@gmail.com', '5_7_Newsletter_abc6@gmail.com', '5_7_Newsletter_abc7@gmail.com', '5_7_Newsletter_abc9@gmail.com']" ,   sent_to =  "['abc@gmaill.com', 'abc2@gmail.com', 'abc3@gmail.com', 'abc4@gmail.com', 'abc5@gmail.com', 'abc6@gmail.com', 'abc7@gmail.com', 'abc8@gmail.com', 'abc9@gmail.com']" where log_id = 5 
`

Comment: See the parameter now, double quotes the query as it is in string from

Comment: Well, should it not be? In which format should it be stored? There's no such thing as list format in SQL as far as I know. Such a thing would be pointless.